# Extract the data array([[array([[ 399.6097561]])]], dtype=object)

Tags: python, numpy

I have the data like this, how can I extract the value `399.6097561` from it?

```
array([[array([[ 399.6097561]])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Do you understand what you have? What have you tried?

Comment: To help people understand how to help you, consider including what you've tried, and why what you tried isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nested multi-dimensional array inside another multi-dimensional array, so you could just index it.

If you have very deeply-nested arrays, using the [`.flatten()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) can be handy to pull out data. I'd suggest trying to avoid such structures in the first place however.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not good to use multi-dimensional array like this, I loaded the data from Matlab to Python. I have solved this question by index as you said

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the outer `object` layer by `.tolist()`.